# call https webservice in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, ssl

I built WCF application hosted on IIS 7 and this application call another web service for third party company . the third party web service using https ssl and i can call it fine throw windows application after snap the certiface but when i am trying to call it using my WCF application i have ssl error as the following :

The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

i belive there are somthing i need to add it to my WCF applicition to call another service with https ssl connection .

any help please ?

Comment: try this. ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

Comment: where i can add it please i need your help

Comment: it is application level override. you should add this to init stage of your application, or before calling you webservice.